# Get current file name after creating executable

Tags: go, path, filenames, getmodulefilename

I can get the current directory and the name of the current `.go` file but if i build a `.exe` from the file with `go build` then i still get the `.go` name.

.../Project/Test/testfile.go

After building `testfile.go` with `go build` i have these:

1) .../Project/Test/testfile.go

2) .../Project/Test/main.exe

When i execute main.exe i get `testfile` But i want to get the `main` name after executing `main.exe`

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "path/filepath"
    "runtime"
    "strings"
)

func GetFileName() string {
    _, fpath, _, ok := runtime.Caller(0)
    if !ok {
        err := errors.New("failed to get filename")
        panic(err)
    }
    filename := filepath.Base(fpath)
    filename = strings.Replace(filename, ".go", "", 1)
    return filename
}

func main() {
    fmt.Print(GetFileName())
}
```

Comment: You could use `os.Args[0]` to obtain the executable name

Comment: @CanobbioE Sorry didn't know it is that easy. U can write a answer so i mark it as solved

Comment: See also [os.Executable](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Executable). Args may not be what you want, but since you haven't told us what you really want we can't recommend one or the other.

Comment: @Peter I want to get the 'executable' name in any situation. With or without a argument or in any path. Also i think always args[0] contains the executable name like in c#. Do you recomment anything better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [os package](https://golang.org/pkg/os/) provides `os.Args[0]` to obtain the executable name, or if you want the whole path you could use `os.Executable`, as [@Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/603316/peter) has suggested

Comment: Args does *not* contain the name of the executable. It's merely the first argument, i.e. "whatever I typed on the shell" (\*waves hands\*). It can be the name of a symlink pointing to the executable, for instance.